# Manipulating Fourier coefficients

Tags: python, arrays, fft, coefficients

I have calculated the coefficients of the discrete Fourier transform of a function. I have also created an array of N=1000 elements containing 1000 equally spaced samples from a single cycle of a square wave.

here is my code

```
 F=zeros(1000)
 F[0:500]=1
 F[500:1000]=-1
 a = rfft(F)
 print a
```

How do I set all but the first 10 Fourier coefficients to zero ?

Comment: Do you want to set them "by force" to zero?

Comment: How would it be done with or without force I don't understand how it could be done without "force"

Comment: tried `a[10:500]=0`?

Comment: doesn't that set the array of F to have all zero but the first 10 ? cause I am looking to change the fourier series

Comment: `F[10:500]=0` would set the array `F`. Setting `a` would change the fourier coefficients computed with `rfft`.

Answer (score 0):

The array `a` should contain 501 complex valued coefficients as returned from [`rfft`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html). Correspondingly to keep only the first 10 coefficients, you can set the remaining coefficients to zero with:

```
a[10:500] = 0
```

Alternatively you can specify the range to go all the way to the last index by using `a[10:-1] = 0`.